# Any good iOS 5 books out yet?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5

Are there any recommended books for developing iPad apps using iOS 5 specifically covering features like storyboards and segues with different examples.

Mainly working on the iPad 2 here but any good iOS 5 book would be welcome.

Many Thanks
Geoff

Comment: What's wrong with [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html)?  If you like, you can print it out, get it bound, and call it a book.

Comment: Ray Wenderlich did a great job with his beta book on iOS 5: http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-5-by-tutorials

Comment: Ray Wenderlich's iOS Apprentice series and his iOS 5 essentials are great.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One book has been released recently:

[iPhone iOS 5 Development Essentials](http://best-gear.org/iphone-ios-5-development-essentials/)

Answer (score 1):

I found *[Beginning iPhone 4 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023024X)* by Mark, Nutting and LaMarche useful, and it now has an iOS 5 edition: *[Beginning iOS 5 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430236051)* (though I haven't read that version). (There's also a followup text, *[More iOS 5 Development: Further Explorations of the iOS SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430238070)*.)

Answer (score 0):

[Head First](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022947.do) coming out in March.  Its an interesting way to learn from these books.